# MySQL Group Concat Single Column NULL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a column that i am looking to retrieve all matches of in one row. I am querying other data as well. Currently i am using group_concat. This has worked great until now. Sometimes there are potential NULL values in this column and this has been preventing anything from being returned.

i have tried various other solutions posted here without success.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
item_num mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE table2 (
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
oneid mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
item_desc varchar(16) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

SELECT item_num, GROUP_CONCAT(item_desc) AS alldesc FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.oneid
```

So basically, there can be several item descripotions that may be NULL; they will be in no particular order either. So i am seeking a list with a placeholder when NULLs arise.

Comment: can you show your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you(use description as empty string when it is NULL)?

```
SELECT item_num, 
       REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(item_desc,' ')), ', ,', ',') AS alldesc 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.oneid
```

Comment: tendecy of this is if there are 3 values with `null` you'll get something like this, `hello, world, , , ,`

Comment: im not sure why, but no. if there are no NULLs it works fine. but if there is a null then an item it still gives nothing

Comment: @JohnWoo: I added the `REPLACE` method to take care of empty commas. Hope that is fine.

Comment: @Foo_Chow can you add sample records with desired outout?

Comment: Last one got it; looks like some of the issue was with the php i used to interpret the results too

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `GROUP BY` in your query. chances are if you have multiple `item_num`, it will always return one row.

```
SELECT   item_num, GROUP_CONCAT(item_desc) AS alldesc 
FROM     table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
            ON table1.id = table2.oneid
GROUP BY item_num
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT item_num, GROUP_CONCAT(ISNULL(item_desc,'')) AS alldesc FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.oneid
```

Comment: tendecy of this is if there are 3 values with `null` you'll get something like this, `hello, world, , , ,`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_num, 
REPLACE(
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      IFNULL(item_desc,'*!*') -- replace this with something not in a normal item_desc
      ORDER BY if(item_desc is null, 1, 0) desc
), '*!*,','') AS alldesc 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.oneid
GROUP BY item_num
```